# How to write an in-place method for strings

Tags: ruby, string, in-place

I want to write a method to trim characters from the end of a string. This is simple enough to do:

```
class String
  def trim(amount)
    self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end
end

my_string = "Hello"
my_string = my_string.trim(1) # => Hell
```

I would rather have this be an in-place method. The naive approach,

```
class String
  def trim(amount)
    self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end

  def trim!(amount)
    self = trim(amount)
  end
end
```

throws the error "Can't change the value of self: self = trim(amount)".

What is the correct way of writing this in-place method? Do I need to manually set the attributes of the string? And if so, how do I access them?

Comment: All of the answers I receieved were great, and I am accepting @falsetru's answer as it most closely resembles my original intent. I will modify it to include both trim() and trim!(), but the principle stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`String#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

```
class String
  def trim(amount)
    self[0..-1] = self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end
end

s = 'asdf'
s.trim(2) # => "as"
s # => "as"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-replace). So it could become:

```
class String
  def trim(amount)
    self[0..-(amount+1)]
  end

  def trim!(amount)
    replace trim(amount)
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but note that in `trim!`, `replace trim(amount)` is sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland fair call - I always tend to get a bit `self` obsessed when writing instance methods :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write as

```
class String
  def trim(amount)
    self.slice(0..-(amount+1))
  end

  def trim!(amount)
    self.slice!(-amount..-1)
    self
  end
end

my_string = "Hello"          
puts my_string.trim(1) # => Hell
puts my_string # => Hello

my_string = "Hello"          
puts my_string.trim!(1) # => Hell
puts my_string # => Hell
```

Read the [`String#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-slice) and [`String#slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-slice-21)

Comment: "Hello".trim(1) should return "Hell"

Comment: @DevonParsons I was customising your code.. and that time it `-` gone.. I didn't notice.. :-) That's a typo. I fixed.